# How do I add a project to a team project?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Some time ago I went to Azure DevOps Services, to create a new Team Project. The name of this Team Project is “Small Apps”.

When I created Small Apps, I created it using Git and Scrum, but didn't add any project a part of the Small Apps team project. Today I had an idea that I wanted to test out. So, I fired up VS 2017 and tried to connect to Small Apps in my Azure DevOps. Nothing doing. Couldn’t find it from VS 2017. I could find other team projects I’ve created in Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) using either TFVC or Git, but I couldn’t find Small Apps.

Why is that?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the project hasn't been deleted?

Comment: Just checked. Small Apps is still in my Azure DevOps workspace.

Comment: Where in VS are you looking for your project? If you created a project but the repo hasn't been created (or cloned in VS) yet, you won't find it in VS. Please (create and) clone the Git repo first, then you can find it on your machine.

Comment: AAARRRGGGHHH! You're right, @rickvdbosch, that's what I forgot to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Where in Visual Studio are you looking for your project?  If you created a project but the repo hasn't been created (or cloned in Visual Studio) yet, you won't find it in Visual Studio.

Please (create and) clone the Git repo first, then you will find it on your machine.